# Facebook API returns to callback and sometimes /me call not working

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm using PHP Facebook API for login flow. *In most of the times this succeeds*. Here and there (I'd estimate 15%), after returning to the callback url, when calling to

```
$url = 'me?fields=username,id';
$data = $this->facebook->api($url);
```

Instead of getting the data I'm getting this exception:

```
An active access token must be used to query information about the current user
```

Can this be somehow related to some sort of wrong `session` handling on my side?

Comment: Can you reproduce the situation where it fails? Perhaps it is happening when someone does not accept the permissions during the login flow?

Comment: i noticed losing data from FB after some minutes like 5-6 when not interacting with FB or its iframe app. what i do is getting the data from facebook once and storing it into a $_SESSION var. from now on i only use the cookie, becouse you are not losing its information until you unset it or close the browser tab.

Comment: @madebydavid I didn't manage to reproduce the situation. I've gotten several complaints from users, and then added an error log which showed me this error

Comment: @ggzone this happens right after login. I actually save the long-lived token afterwards and use that. What var are you saving in the session?

Comment: I would first add some code to check the error returned from the FB login flow to check if the problem is only happening for users who do not accept the permissions - see the details of reading the error on the redirect_uri page here - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/ if that doesn't work, I would log out the user agents to see if there is a pattern (perhaps not working for one browser) and then if that doesn't yield any results, I would think about retrying the auth by sending the user back to the login flow - have a max number of retry tho.

Comment: all information given by some applicaion for example. after the facebook apprequest you can receive the data with the facebook class in the API -> $facebook->getUser()... this is what i store in the session

Comment: @madebydavid done as u suggested. Still seeing sometimes that in the $_GET there is no evidence of an error that user didn't accept permissions, and `?code` and `&state` seem ok. Still `/me` returns `An active access token must be used to query information about the current user` Any idea?

Comment: Strange, maybe the FB SDK is not swapping the code for an access token in certain situations - try calling `$this->facebook->getUser()` first before the `->api` call - this should force it to swap the code for an access token.

Comment: May be need to reset the access token before making a call http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20918712/how-to-use-graph-api-access-token-in-php-for-facebook-sdk/20919013#20919013